# Convert string of json data into array of array of dictionaries in java

Tags: java, arrays, json, dictionary

I have an array filled with arrays of dictionaries. I am sending this array as a string to a mysql database for storage and retrieval. The number of arrays and number of dictionaries vary with each entry. In objective-C it is pretty simple, I use this code to move to and from an array to a string.

```
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:itemListArray options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSData *td = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSMutableArray *newArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:td options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

This works great for populating my tableviews and accessing the data as needed for details.

I am stuck on how to do this in java. Here is an example of the string as received from the webservice.

```
[[{"Person":"Me","PersonID":0,"Description":"jake"},{"Person":"Me","PersonID":0,"Description":"mickey"}],[{"Person":"You","PersonID":1,"Description":"sophia"},{"Person":"You","PersonID":1,"Description":"jasmine"}]]
```

As you can see it is a 2 dimensional array with 2 arrays and 2 dictionaries per array. How can I convert this into an array of array of dictionaries in java? I've tried something like this where ed2 is a string as shown above.

```
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(ed2);
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(ed2);
```

But both of those throw exceptions and will not compile. Really new to java but every close example I've seen makes use of these objects. Would be awesome if there is a similar function to objective-c to make it easy that I can't seem to find but I can always parse the string and populate the arrays by brute force if needed.

EDIT:
Here is a code snippet up to the problem.

```
// JSONArray from server, pull out the first object in the array
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) getItem(position);
if (jsonObject.has("EventData")) {
      eventData = jsonObject.optString("EventData");
}
// clean up some aspects of the string (this will be fixed later, extra characters will not be stored. 
String ed2 = (eventData.replace("\\", ""));
    // ed2 at this point: [[{"Person":"Me","PersonID":0,"Description":"jake"},{"Person":"Me","PersonID":0,"Description":"mickey"}],[{"Person":"You”,"PersonID":1,"Description":"sophia"},{"Person":"You”,"PersonID":1,"Description":"jasmine"}]]
try {
    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(ed2);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    // error: Method threw 'java.lang.NullPointerException' exception. Cannot evaluate org.json.JSONArray.toString()
}
try {
    JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(ed2);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    // error: Method threw 'java.lang.NullPointerException' exception. Cannot evaluate org.json.JSONObject.toString() 
}
```

Comment: "throw exceptions and will not compile" -- what now? Can you give more details please about the compile error or exception? Which JSON library are you using?

Comment: Not compile errors, my mistake. They are runtime errors. Exception on jsonarray convert: `Method threw 'java.lang.NullPointerException' exception. Cannot evaluate org.json.JSONArray.toString()`     Exception to jsonobject convert: `Method threw 'java.lang.NullPointerException' exception. Cannot evaluate org.json.JSONObject.toString()`  Using org.json libraries

Comment: Please construct a minimal runnable code snippet which reproduces the error. Looking at your example string: Is that the actual string you're trying to parse or did you manually edit it for posting here? Reason I'm asking: The second quote character is not a "dumb" straight quote (`"` vs. `”`) and will not be parsed correctly, I assume.

Comment: Not sure where the  `”` instead of `"` came from but this is not how it looks in the string. Must be an editing error. Edited the post to include a code snippet.